# How to get selected date from paper-date-picker

Tags: jquery, polymer

Does anyone know how to get the selected date out of a paper-date-picker? I've tried creating the widget with

```
<paper-date-picker id="cbxstartdate" class="dp"></paper-date-picker>
```

This worked, but I've tried reading the selected date when an external button is clicked with something like

```
var startDate = $("#cbxstartdate).attr("immediateDate");
```

but all I get is undefined.

Thanks, Gary

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the paper-date-picker, but assuming it is this one:  https://github.com/bendavis78/paper-date-picker

Setup a binding as in the example to a local variable and just pull the data out of there.  If you don't want to do that then what about somethign like

```
var startDate = this.$.cbxstartdate.date;
```

Comment: Using `this` assumes the user is clicking on the paper-date-picker to run this code, but I have 2 instances of paper-date-picker, one for a startdate and another for the enddate.  So I have an OK button separate from both instances that the user clicks to call my javascript code.  I tried doing `$("#cbxstartDate").$.cbxstartdate.date;`, but this produced an error of cbxstartdate being undefined.  Any suggestions?

Comment: A double quote character missing right after #cbxstartdate (See your single of JS)

Comment: Is the `<paper-date-picker>` the element on this page? https://www.webcomponents.org/element/bendavis78/paper-date-picker/elements/paper-date-picker

Comment: var startDate = $("#cbxstartdate").date;